# Magento Show parent and subcategories

Tags: magento, navigation

How do I show on a category page in Magento only the parent category and subcategories?

When a subcategory is clicked the navigation has to stay the same.

Example:
If I have

**Category 1**

- subcat 1
- subcat 2
- subcat 3

After clicking on any subcategory (say subcat 1), I want the same i.e :

**Category 1**

- **subcat 1**
- subcat 2
- subcat 3

What I got now:

```
<?php
 if (Mage::registry('current_category'))
{
  echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();
} 
?> 

 <?php
    $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');

    if ( $currentCat->getParentId() == Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() )
    {
        // current category is a toplevel category
        $loadCategory = $currentCat;

    }
    else
    {
        // current category is a sub-(or subsub-, etc...)category of a toplevel category
        // load the parent category of the current category
        $loadCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getParentId());
        // @TODO enhance for more nested category levels to display sub-categories
    }    
    $subCategories = explode(',', $loadCategory->getChildren());

    foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
    {
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);

        if($cat->getIsActive())
        {
            echo '<a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a> ';
        }
    }
?>
```

But of course this isn't working correct but I can't find a good solution so that Category 1 stays the same when I press subcat 1.

And it would be wonderful if the selected subcategory would be bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, in place of

```
<?php
 if (Mage::registry('current_category'))
    {
      echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();
    } 
?>
```

Try using

```
<?php
function getParentTopCategory($c)
    {
        if($c->getLevel() == 2){
            return $c;
        } else {
            $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($c->getParentId());
            return getParentTopCategory($parentCategory);
        }
    }

 if (Mage::registry('current_category'))
    {
      $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
      $t = getParentTopCategory($category);
      echo $t->getName();
    } 
?>
```

It should work.

**EDIT:
Here is your complete solution :-**

```
$crcat = Mage::registry('current_category')->getName(); //The current category name is stored in $crcat
function getParentTopCategory($c)
    {
        if($c->getLevel() == 2){
            return $c;
        } else {
            $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($c->getParentId());
            return getParentTopCategory($parentCategory);
        }
    }

 if (Mage::registry('current_category'))
{
  $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
        $t = getParentTopCategory($category);
        if($crcat == $t->getName())                 //Check if current category is the topmost category
            echo "<b>".$t->getName()."</b>";        //If yes display it as bold (Currently Selected)
        else                                        //
            echo $t->getName();                     //Otherwise display it as normal

        echo "<br>";
} 
?> 

 <?php
    $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');

    if ( $currentCat->getParentId() == Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() )
    {
        // current category is a toplevel category
        $loadCategory = $currentCat;

    }
    else
    {
        // current category is a sub-(or subsub-, etc...)category of a toplevel category
        // load the parent category of the current category
        $loadCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getParentId());
        // @TODO enhance for more nested category levels to display sub-categories
    }    
    $subCategories = explode(',', $loadCategory->getChildren());

    foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
    {
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);

        if($cat->getIsActive())
        {
            if($crcat == $cat->getName())                                                   //Check if current category is this subcategory
                echo '<b><a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a></b>'.'</br>'; //If yes display it as bold (Currently Selected)
            else                                                                            //
                echo '<a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a>'.'</br>';        //Otherwise display it as normal
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thnx! That was what I was looking for. I created a list of it. But now the second question. How could I add the "active" state of a category?

Comment: What do you mean by add "active" state of a category? Do you want to check if the category is active??
Also on which of the categories do you want to apply this condition to, the topmost category or the children?
You could use if($category->getIsActive()) to check that.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. So if someone is in subcategory 2 then it has to be bold :) I cant get it to work with  if($category->getIsActive()).

Comment: Ok, I understand. If I'm not wrong, when you say **active** you actually mean it should be **selected**.

You want the selected category to be bold. Right?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Check the edit, it does what you require.